# How To sum timestamp column that is saved as varchar

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum, timestamp

I have a table that has timestamp data in it but the type of the column is character varying. i.e.

```
totaltime
character varying
0000:00:08.00
0000:12:39.00
0000:01:09.00
0000:00:02.00
0000:03:53.00
```

Is there an easy way to take sum of the column?

Comment: @paqogomez: Cast to interval, not timestamp. Summing timestamps is literally nonsense. Postgresql will throw an error if you try; other dbms might return numerical nonsense. (MySQL, for example.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not a timestamp but an interval:

```
select '0000:00:08.00'::timestamp;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "0000:00:08.00"
LINE 1: select '0000:00:08.00'::timestamp;

select '0000:00:08.00'::interval;
 interval 
----------
 00:00:08
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Comment: Right. Summing timestamps makes no sense. "One hour plus two hours" (summing intervals) makes sense. "1 o'clock plus 2 o'clock" does not.  But the intervals *are* in a varchar column. Who knows what else awaits?